# What to create new post using wp_insert_post, but it repeat the post infinitely

Tags: php, sql

this is my source

```
    global $page;
    $page_exists = $page->post_title;

    $another_db_user = 'user';
    $another_db_pass = 'pass';
    $another_db_name = 'name';
    $another_db_host = 'localhost';
    $another_tb_prefix = 'wp_';

    $mydb = new wpdb($another_db_user,$another_db_pass,$another_db_name,$another_db_host);

    $mydb->set_prefix($another_tb_prefix);

    $result = $mydb->get_results("
    SELECT  
    m0.post_title,  
    m0.id,  
    m0.post_name,
    m0.guid  
    FROM ( select post_title, id, guid, post_name from wp_posts where post_type = 'bio' AND post_status = 'publish'  ) AS m0 
    ");


    foreach ($result as $value) {


    if( $value->post_title == $page_exists  ) {

    }

    else {
    $my_access = Array(
    'post_author' => '1',
    'post_title' => ''.$value->post_title.'',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'ping_status' => 'closed',
    'post_name' => ''.$value->post_name.'',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent' => '115822',
    'page_template' => 'template-profile-info.php'
              );

    wp_insert_post($my_access);

    }

    }
```

Comment: Thank  you. 
But im beginner in this.

How should i do this??

Comment: i want to get the post from different database( Site A ) and post automatically to other site ( Site B ).

Comment: so i just want to stop to repeat the same post.

i know to use IF could be the result but i dont now how to use it.

Comment: when the post title are the same , to do nothing i think.....

Comment: because the ID's will going to be different every post, so cant find any same post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing I just set the external DB to the current DB. As you can see on your own setup they should all fail the check to be created because they all exist (`B -> B`).

Obviously on your ( `A -> B` ) setup you will get many that will pass as long as the slug doesn't already exist.

I chose `post_name` over `post_title` because `post_name` has to be unique. You could also check against `guid`.

```
function wpse_20160318_do_db_sync() {

    // set the DB creds
    $another_db_user   = DB_USER;
    $another_db_pass   = DB_PASSWORD;
    $another_db_name   = DB_NAME;
    $another_db_host   = DB_HOST;
    $another_tb_prefix = 'wp_';
    $post_type         = 'post';

    // setup the DB connection
    $mydb = new wpdb( $another_db_user, $another_db_pass, $another_db_name, $another_db_host );

    $mydb->set_prefix( $another_tb_prefix );

    // query the DB
    $result = $mydb->get_results(
        "
    SELECT ID, post_title, post_name, guid
    FROM $mydb->posts
    WHERE post_status = 'publish'
        AND post_type = '$post_type'
    "
    );

    // for all the results, let's check against the slug.
    foreach ( $result as $r ) {

        // see if we can find it...
        $post = get_page_by_path( $r->post_name, OBJECT, $post_type );

        if ( ! $post ) {
            // We're cool, let's create this one.
            echo PHP_EOL . 'Let\'s make a new post for ' . $r->post_title . PHP_EOL;
        }
        else {
            // No need to duplicate this one
            echo PHP_EOL . 'Post already exists for ' . $post->post_title . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

// using on init to make sure the DB is ready to go
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_20160318_do_db_sync' );
```

---

The Flow of data will look like:

**Query**

```
$result = $mydb->get_results(
    "
    SELECT {PROPERTY}
    FROM $mydb->posts
    "
);
```

**Loop**

```
foreach ( $result as $r ) {
```

**Create**

```
$data = Array(
    '{PROPERTY}' => $r->{PROPERTY},
    'post_name'  => $r->post_name,
);

wp_insert_post($data);
```

---

### Working Version

You can use this on your own db if you comment out the testing block. Set `$another_post_type` to and CPT in your WP and it will generate a `page` for each `$post_type`. The meta key will also keep track of the `ID` used from the DB. Since the search doesn't specify a publish type, a new page will not be created if a  duplicate page is in the trash until the trash is emptied.

```
function wpse_20160318_do_db_sync() {

    $another_db_user = 'user';
    $another_db_pass = 'pass';
    $another_db_name = 'name';
    $another_db_host = 'localhost';

// FOR TESTING SAME DB
//
//  $another_db_user = DB_USER;
//  $another_db_pass = DB_PASSWORD;
//  $another_db_name = DB_NAME;
//  $another_db_host = DB_HOST;

    $another_tb_prefix   = 'wp_';
    $another_post_type   = 'bio';
    $another_post_status = 'publish';

    $mydb = new wpdb( $another_db_user, $another_db_pass, $another_db_name, $another_db_host );
    $mydb->set_prefix( $another_tb_prefix );
    $result = $mydb->get_results(
        "
    SELECT ID, post_title, post_name, guid, post_content, post_excerpt, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_modified, post_modified_gmt
    FROM $mydb->posts
    WHERE post_status = '$another_post_status'
        AND post_type = '$another_post_type'
    "
    );

    $another_db_post_id_meta_key = 'another_db_post_id';

    $post_type = 'page';
    $mods      = array (
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_author'    => '1',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status'    => 'closed',
        'page_template'  => 'template-profile-info.php',
        'post_parent'    => '115822',
        'post_type'      => $post_type,
    );

    foreach ( $result as $r ) {

        $post_title = wp_strip_all_tags( $r->post_title );

        // see if we can find it by title...
        $post = get_page_by_title( $post_title, OBJECT, $post_type );

        if ( ! $post ) {

            // title wasn't found... but let's check the meta
            $meta_args  = array (
                'post_type'  => array ( $post_type ),
                'meta_query' => array (
                    array (
                        'key'     => $another_db_post_id_meta_key,
                        'compare' => '=',
                        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                        'value'   => $r->ID,
                    ),
                ),
            );
            $meta_posts = get_posts( $meta_args );

            // set the post to the first item in the list, if it isn't empty
            if ( ! empty( $meta_posts ) ) {
                list( $post ) = $meta_posts;
            }
        }

        if ( ! $post ) {

            // Can't find the post, let's create this one.

            // Data from another DB
            $clone = array (
                'post_title'        => $post_title,
                'post_content'      => $r->post_content,
                'post_excerpt'      => $r->post_excerpt,
                'post_date'         => $r->post_date,
                'post_date_gmt'     => $r->post_date_gmt,
                'post_modified'     => $r->post_modified,
                'post_modified_gmt' => $r->post_modified_gmt,
            );

            // Merge with our defaults
            $args = array_merge( $clone, $mods );

            // create new post
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $args );

            if ( $post_id instanceof WP_Error ) {
                // failed to create new post
                // wp_die( 'Failed to create ' . $post_id );
            }
            else {
                // new post created
                $post = get_post( $post_id );

                // add clone tag that we can check later
                add_post_meta( $post->ID, $another_db_post_id_meta_key, $r->ID, false );
            }
        }
        else {
            // no need to dup
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!

ill try but dint get any result.

where is the wp_insert_post??

Comment: i try but get nothing.....

Comment: get_page_by_path will get the post ID right??

i think that the post will have different ID's all the time so, can use it....

Comment: ok, but i still get the same result....

Comment: sorry, i mean that the post still duplicate with the same title.

Comment: i can give the access to my site but ,how?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!

THIS IS MY SOLUTION SOURCE!!!

GENIUS!!!

Comment: HI!!

thank you the last time!!

i have another issue...

now, i want to compare by the slug, but not by title

// see if we can find it by title...
$post = get_page_by_title( $post_title, OBJECT, $post_type );

Answer (score 0):

I am directly referring to the table **wp_posts** instead of using any prefix as you definitely know the table name else you can set and use the prefix.

```
// Get all posts in the current database
$this_posts = get_posts(
                array(
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'numberposts' => -1
                )
            );

// Pull all titles for duplication checking
$this_post_titles = wp_list_pluck( $this_posts, 'post_title' );

// Set other database credentials and connect
$another_db_user = 'user';
$another_db_pass = 'pass';
$another_db_name = 'name';
$another_db_host = 'host';
$another_tb_prefix = 'wp_';

$mydb = new wpdb( $another_db_user, $another_db_pass, $another_db_name, $another_db_host );

// Get all data
$result = $mydb->get_results(
                        "SELECT post_title, post_name FROM wp_posts 
                        WHERE post_type = 'bio' AND post_status = 'publish'"
                    );

// Loop through each result and insert if it's not there in the system    
foreach ( $result as $value ) {
    if ( in_array( $value->post_title, $this_post_titles ) ) {
        echo 'Already exisis: ' . $value->post_title;
    } else {
        $my_access = array(
                    'post_author' => '1',
                    'post_title' => $value->post_title,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'comment_status' => 'closed',
                    'ping_status' => 'closed',
                    'post_name' => $value->post_name,
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'post_parent' => '115822',
                    'page_template' => 'template-profile-info.php'
                  );

        $inserted = wp_insert_post( $my_access );

        if ( $inserted )
        {
            echo 'Added: ' . $value->post_title;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Failed: ' . $value->post_title;
        }
    }

    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: thank you.

i try but get no result...

Comment: Please be specific when you say "no result". Are you checking the records in the admin end or database? I have modified to get all pages in the system, then check their titles as you are finally inserting as page. Also please make necessary changes as per your requirement, you should use proper values for some variables.